# Google Analytics Tag Manager: {{event}} is missing in selection for rule

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I'm trying to create a click oder link click listener in the Google Analytics Tag Manager. In the guides and even the official manual I found that you setup a rule to active the Tracking of links getting clicked: [Google Analytics support reference](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3420054?hl=en&ref_topic=3002579)

In the rule you define that `{{event}}` equals `gtm.linkClick` (see outdated manual).

The thing is that I can't define `{{event}}`. It just doesn't appear in the select menu. It almost seems like a Google bug. Is there a new way how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Tag Manager Console, whatever you see in curly braces, **they are defined as macros**

> Curly Braces means Macros

If you don't see `{{event}}` in the list,

check if a Macro named **event** exist or not. **If not** create a Macro named event with type `Custom Event`

Hope this helps.